# no such method exception removeAccount targeting API < 22

Tags: android

i am using removeAccount method to remove a custom created account and i am getting the 'no such method exception' in devices with API < 22.

```
        AccountManager.get(mContext).removeAccount(getAccountByType(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.account_type)), null, null, null);
```

My manifest file has the following permission as docs stated:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API < 22 you need to use the deprecated method instead. In your code you will need an if and use the right method based on device API level.

You probably need to do something similar:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
     removeAccount (Account account, AccountManagerCallback<Boolean> callback, 
                    Handler handler);
} else {
     removeAccount (Account account, Activity activity, 
                    AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a method which was added into API22. There are 2 versions of this method. One which can be used for versions older than API22 and the one you are using can be used from/after API 22.

[image]

Below method was deprecated in API level 22.

---

So you can do it like

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
    // Depricated version
} else {
   // New version
}
```

Comment: what about the deprecated version...is there a problem using it?

Comment: No in current you wont be in trouble. They will be available until Android gives you another way to remove accounts from below API22.